# Forgot my password to /register-based server

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

I registered into the server and was authenticated by using /register  and I haven't been on the server since and when I just tried to go onto it, I forgot my password and it won't let me reregister? What do I do?

Comment: This is dependent on the specific server. Contact a server op or admin for help.

Answer (score 2):

Send a email to the Admin of the server.

With the mod to allow register users, your password is stored in the database and only the Admin can change it.