# I Forgot my MC PE External server password and now I can't play.

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, hosting

What can I do? I've forgot my login password for external MC PE servers and now I can't join any of them because I forgot. Now what? Is there a way to get your password back?

Comment: Contact the server Admin.

Comment: I closed this as unclear, but my guess as to what they are asking is a duplicate of [Forgot my password to /register-based server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/164406/185203) - this is so poorly written it's hard to tell

Answer (score 1):

Your have to hit the button on the top right and click options. Where you see your mcpe name, tap it and change it to a new name, so you can have a new password. WARNING do this in a world of your own.then go on a server and type /register YourPassword